# How to install MySql on Ubuntu 10

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, installation, startup

I have done the following:

```
shell> sudo apt-get install mysql-server-core-5.1
shell> sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.1
```

Both seemed to complete fine with no errors. I have the following present:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

However if I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
```

for the simple reason that in fact this directory does not exist. Now the correct way to start the daemon is apparently:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

however this script does not seem to exist either. So has my install totally messed up, or is there a step I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The way to install MySql on Ubuntu 10.04 is as follows:

```
shell> sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

which will install everything, client and dependencies. You will prompted for a root password duing install. And that's it. When the install has completed mysqld will be up and running, and will start on boot. To connect to it:

```
shell> mysql -u root -p
```

and then add other users as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start mysql by using sudo. The easiest way is

```
sudo start mysql
```

Daemons usually always have to started with root privileges.

However, after the installation, the mysql daemon (mysqld) is very liklely already running. You can check this out with

```
sudo status mysql
```